# CSS Transform on Chrome shows element edges

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transforms

I'm trying to apply a scaleX transform on a div that contains spans. The transform is working just fine but when it is not unity, the edges of the spans do not seem to touch resulting in a visible line between them.

Here's an example

[image]

and here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jimwe/b38dmm17/1/):

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="line">
        <span class="cell">A</span><span class="cell">B</span><span class="cell">C</span><span class="cell">D</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

.container {
    background-color: black;
    width: 350px;
}
.page {
    padding: 10px;
    transform: scaleX(1.2);
}
.line {
    padding-left:25px;
}
.cell {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Change the value of the scaleX transform to 1.0 and the edges disappear. change to 1.1 and then 1.2 and you can see the transform otherwise seems to work nicely. Seems to be a Chrome thang - firefox and edge don't exhibit the problem. I'm fairly new to CSS so any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your cell

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: I tested this idea with latest Chrome on Windows and it seems that the browser now recognizes the back-face-visibility style (not -webkit any longer). However it doesn't seem to solve this problem. Do I need to apply some other style along with it perhaps?

Comment: @jimwe changing your transform to scaleX(1.2) perspective(0.01px) works in testing, but there is a side effect of slightly blurry text.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a long standing quirk for inline elements. A very pragmatic solution is to remove the closing tags for your `<span>` tags (all browsers support this)

Check also this link [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Finally you can use Flexbox to fix this problem

```css
.container {
  background-color: black;
  width: 350px;
}
.page {
 padding: 10px;
 transform: scaleX(1.3);
}
.line {
  padding-left:25px;
}
.cell {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="line">
        <span class="cell">A<span class="cell">B<span class="cell">C<span class="cell">D
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea of removing the end tag on spans. It works great! However I don't see </span> listed as an optional tag here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags so I'm hesitant to use this option. I'm playing with Flexbox but haven't quite hit on the right combination yet. When I find a working flex model, I'll post it here.

Comment: Sure.. it is a bit hacky... my understanding is that browser can deal with tags with no closing because the infer that the next element cannot exists without closing the previous one. It is in XHTML where XML force you to actually close the tag.  But if you find a flexbox, let me know.. I thing that is your cleaner solution. Good Luck